# Docker linux kill process script when time/memory limit exceeded

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker

I am trying to run a python code in my docker container. I have set up run.sh script as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ulimit -s 5
timeout --signal=SIGTERM 5 python3 main.py
exit $?
```

main.py:

```
def factorial(x):
    """This is a recursive function
    to find the factorial of an integer"""

    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (x * factorial(x-1))


num = 900
print("The factorial of", num, "is", factorial(num))
```

I run my image that has the above script as follow:

```
container = subprocess.run(["docker", "run", "mycontainertag"],capture_output=True)
```

However it is not terminating the process using the factorial code, despite exceeding time and memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in [docker](/questions/tagged/docker), rather with the `ulimit`.

`ulimit -s 5` command limits the stack trace for all the following commands in the same shell, the problem is that 5 does not probably mean what you think. You have set the stack limit to 5 * 1024 bytes (5 Kb), which is too low considering that you have both `timeout` and `python3`.

In my machine, for example, just to run `run.sh` I need more than 100 Kb. This value depends on the OS of your machine, on its current status, on the python version you are using (I guess), and from other variables too.

Comment: If that's the case, why does my command still run despite being lower than the limit?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood this sentence then *"However it is not terminating the process using the factorial code, despite exceeding time and memory limit."*. What happens when you run it?

Comment: It proceeds to run the code and output the result, despite it being obviously taking more resources (memory and time) than I allowed using the timeout

Comment: Then please provide other information like the Dockerfile so that we can reproduce the issue.